# Join and rename single attribute to model in Rails 4 with ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

We need to join a single column from another table in a model. That attribute is named the same as one in the model itself, and as such needs to be renamed/aliased when joined on the model.

If the attribute on the model was the same, we could easily do a join:

```
def self.default_scope
  joins("LEFT JOIN slugs ON slugs.type = 'shop' AND slugs.target = shops.id")
end
```

But since we only want the `slugs.name` attribute (renamed to `slug`), the only solution I've come up with so far, is this crazy scope:

```
def self.default_scope
  select("shops.id AS id, shops.name AS name, […15 more…], slugs.name AS slug")
  .joins("LEFT JOIN slugs ON slugs.type = 'shop' AND slugs.target = shops.id")
end
```

Is there any simpler ways to do this, or do we have to live with this abomination?

Comment: try to not use hardcoded  comparison in left join instead place it in where clause (in your exa. remove "slugs.type = 'shop'" this from left join and place it in where clase )

Comment: How would I do this?
I figured it would be
`select("shops.*, slugs.name AS slug").joins("LEFT JOIN slugs ON slugs.target = shops.id").where({"slugs.type" => 'shop'})`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't have knowledge of in which framework you are writing code, but I think where clause should be .where("slugs.type = "'shop')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following
Replace select Statement

```
select("shops.id AS id, shops.name AS name, […15 more…], slugs.name AS slug")
```

With

```
select("shops.*, slugs.name AS slug")
```